# Yocto build not including files in sdcard image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build an SDK into my sysroot on my yocto build. However when i compile my build i get no errors and everything appears to have worked fine.

When i flash my SD  card and run it on my board and go to look for my files, they arent there.

here is my .bb file which is used to install the SDK i want to use.

```
giffgaff-connectDESCRIPTION = "azure"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c"
LICENSE = "MIT"
SECTION = "applications"
PRIORITY = "optional"
DEPENDS = "mono"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${WORKDIR}/git/LICENSE;md5=4283671594edec4c13aeb073c219237a"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
SRC_URI = "git://git@bitbucket.org/condecosoftware/azure-iot-sdk-c;protocol=ssh;branch=master"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "imx6qsabresd"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"

do_compile() {
  echo libdir: ${libdir}
  echo Files : FILES_${PN}
  echo "compiler: ${CC}"
  echo "sysroot: ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}"
  export SYSROOT=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}
  cd ${WORKDIR}/git/build_all/linux/
  ./build.sh --toolchain-file toolchain-yocto.cmake -cl --sysroot=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET} --install-path-prefix ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}
  cd ../..
  cmake -P cmake/iotsdk_linux/cmake_install.cmake
}

do_install() {
    cd git
    pwd
    echo ${D}
    echo ${libdir}
    install -d 0755  ${D}${libdir}

    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/umqtt/libumqtt.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/uamqp/libuamqp.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/c-utility/libaziotsharedutil.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/iothub_client/libiothub_client_http_transport.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/iothub_client/libiothub_client.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/iothub_client/libiothub_client_amqp_ws_transport.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/iothub_client/libiothub_client_amqp_transport.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/iothub_client/libiothub_client_mqtt_transport.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/iothub_client/libiothub_client_mqtt_ws_transport.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/serializer/libserializer.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0755 ./cmake/iotsdk_linux/iothub_service_client/libiothub_service_client.a ${D}${libdir}/
}

do_fetch_extra(){
    cd ${WORKDIR}/git/
    git submodule update --init --recursive
}

addtask fetch_extra after do_unpack before do_patch
```

Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **${WORKDIR}** variable? This variable holds the pathname of the work directory of recipe being build. So every file fetched from git can be accessed from there, I presume. For example:

install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/cmake/iotsdk_linux/umqtt/libumqtt.a ${D}${libdir}/

Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably need to add

```
PACKAGES =+ "${PN}-staticdev"  
FILES_${PN}-staticdev += "${libdir}/*.a"
```

to ship every files you installed into your image.
You can also add every files one by one instead of wildcard.

Some remarks:

For git submodules, you can use gitsm:// url, it will initialize every submodules.

You can also put the following instruction to avoid doing some change dir in recipe.

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

By the way, you can look this OE recipe for Azure from Intel meta-iot-cloud layer. It is python recipe, but it depends on C iot sdk, it can be inspiring:

https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/meta-iot-cloud/blob/master/recipes-azure/azure-iot-sdk/azure-iot-sdk_1.1.23.bb